# mvn compile priority to using jar in repository or source module in project?

Tags: java, maven

When using mvn compile, if a dependency exists in the private repository and is also present as a module within the project, does Maven prioritize compiling from the source code of the module, or does it use the precompiled JAR from the private repository for compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two cases in multi module projects:

#### 1. build whole project with all modules

In suche scenario, as class path for depended module - output of depended module compilation is used

executing: `mvn clean compile -X` we see:

```
[DEBUG] Classpath:
[DEBUG]  .../apache/maven-plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/target/classes
...
[DEBUG]  .../apache/maven-plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-api/target/classes
...
[DEBUG]  .../apache/maven-plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/target/classes
...
```

#### 2. build only one module

In this case precompiled jars from local repo are used.

after executing: `mvn clean compile  -X -pl maven-plugin-tools-annotations` we see:

```
[DEBUG] Classpath:
[DEBUG]  .../apache/maven-plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/target/classes
...
[DEBUG]  .../.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-api/3.10.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-plugin-tools-api-3.10.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
...
[DEBUG]  .../.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.10.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-plugin-annotations-3.10.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
...
```

Comment: That second one will only happen if you have done an `mvn install` once upfront (Maven 3.X) ...which means to consume the depended artifacts from the local cache anyway... In MVN4 it looks the same as in 1.